# Access Reports - Draw border around multiple controls based on largest height

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, report

I am working on a Microsoft Access Report. For aesthetic purposes, I am wanting multiple text boxes to grow vertically together.

I know this can't happen natively, but I have come across a solution that should be working but just isn't executing properly.

My plan is to set the borders of the text boxes transparent, and then use code to find the largest height of them, and draw a rectangle around all the boxes afterwards. I have put "Border" in the tag property of the boxes I am looking to draw around.  The code I have is follows:

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Dim intMaxHeight As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim lngHilite As Long
    lngHilite = 10092543   'pale yellow
    'Find highest control in Detail section that has a tag property of "Border"
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(0).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Border" Then
            If ctl.Height > intMaxHeight Then
                intMaxHeight = ctl.Height
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Draw a box around each control in Detail that has a tag property of "Border"
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(0).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Border" Then
            'make the background pale yellow
             Me.Line (ctl.Left, ctl.Top)- _
                Step(ctl.Width, intMaxHeight), lngHilite, BF
            Me.Line (ctl.Left, ctl.Top)- _
                Step(ctl.Width, intMaxHeight), vbBlack, B
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is giving me pale yellow boxes the same width as the controls I have tagged, but on the two pages preceding the boxes. The yellow boxes are also far too long.

I have also tried using the same code but in the `Detail_Format` section. This gives me yellow boxes the right width AND height, but just on the page before the actual details. So it is drawing the boxes, but just not in the right spot in my report.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT -

This is where I am adding the code
[image: Code]

Thank you.

Comment: Trying code in Format section. Boxes are yellow and they are on every page but not getting adjusted height. Code is not reading height of grown textboxes, only picking up height set in design.

Comment: Now tried in Print section. Code works perfectly.

Comment: Not sure I replicated properly but try casting control to textbox and then setting the textbox properties:For Each ctl In Me.Section(0).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Border" Then
            If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            Dim currentTextBox As TextBox
            Set currentTextBox = ctl
            currentTextBox.BackColor = lngHilite
            currentTextBox.Height = intMaxHeight
            End If

Comment: @June7 Maybe I am putting it in the wrong section. This is what I would have though the "Print section" would be but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that is where I put code. Why does the text code show `FormatCount` instead of `PrintCount` whereas image shows `PrintCount`?

Comment: @June7 I have no idea. But I have just tried both and neither work for me. Using ```PrintCount``` puts yellow boxes behind the front two pages of the report regardless of whether the code is ```Detail_Format``` or ```Detail_Print```. ```FormatCount``` does the right sizes yellow boxes on the wrong spot of the report when ```Detail_Format```, and does nothing on ```Detail_Print```

Comment: Whether the argument is FormatCount or PrintCount seems to be irrelevant. I cannot replicate the described issue.

Comment: @June7 When opening the report with a blank query (i.e. no data), the code works perfectly and it borders the right boxes. But as soon as the report actually has data in it, the code breaks and boxes don't go in the right spot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Still can't replicate issue. My report has data and code works. Could post to a forum that allows attaching files for download and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: @June7 Unfortunately I can't do that for confidentiality reasons (I wish I could). But I'm one step closer. First - when the text boxes grow and break over a page, it seems to break the code, and I get boxes behind the length of the entire document. Second - when the boxes don't grow past their default size (the minimum I have set in the design section), the boxes aren't drawn. Any ideas?

Comment: You would have to sanitize db - remove confidential data and use 'dummy' records. AhHa, none of my boxes had to break over a page. And default size was 1 line so size never less than that. No, I do not know how to fix that, if it is even possible.